# Waiting for all controllers to load during run method

Tags: angularjs

I need to do a broadcast when the page loads. The problem is that the controller never catches the broadcast (my guess is that this is because it hasn't been properly loaded). I have done some research on how to wait for the controllers to be loaded and I've found that I can get a list with all loaded controllers with something like this:

```
searchApp.controller()._invokeQueue
```

If I put a breakpoint in the script in the module/controller (the result is roughly the same) I get a list that contains the `$injector`, factory methods - `broadcast` and the `directives`. Even if I am in the controller `_invokeQueue` doesn't contain my controllers.

So how can I wait for the controllers to properly load or get the list of loaded controllers?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  I'm not sure if you are going in the right direction.

Comment: I am doing an `$http GET` to fetch some data from the server and while this is processed I want to show a progress overlay on the page. The call is done in the `run` method of the module and I need to let the controller that is taking care of the results to alter the DOM and show that overlay until all the data has been loaded.

Comment: You don't need to do anything in your controller, just set a variable in your $rootScope saying something like `rootData.loaded=false` before you do the GET and then once you have your data you can do a `rootData.loaded=true`.  Then you can show/hide your overlay using `ng-hide` or `ng-show`

Comment: Ah OK. I'll give that a try.I didn't know I can use `ng-hide`/`ng-show` based on a variable that's on the `$rootScope` level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable on the `$rootScope` and then show/hide your overlay based on that variable.  I would suggest that your controller and/or `ng-view` not be defined on the `body` tag but rather in a child element that way you can define your overlay outside of that "view".

Here a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bazwsHiZaTaZid76Me9d?p=preview) showing how it works.

Comment: I tried this today. Seems to be working fine. Thanks!